# Use of tool like LowKey or Fawkes in mobile app to cloak image

Tags: flutter, artificial-intelligence, mobile-application, face-detection, cloaking

My goal is to prevent AI facial detection tools to use images uploaded in my mobile app.so that they can't train their facial recognition models using the images uploaded in my app.

I searched for tools like [Fawkes](https://sandlab.cs.uchicago.edu/fawkes/) & [Lowkey](https://lowkey.umiacs.umd.edu/) but couldn't find a proper way to integrate them in mobile app. Fawkes can be used as an API for private or educational purpose but i need for commercial use.

Can anyone help me find any proper methods/tools/algorithoms to cloak images uploaded in a mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

It's a valid concern to want to protect user privacy by preventing AI facial detection tools from utilizing images uploaded in your mobile app for training purposes. While tools like Fawkes and Lowkey provide some level of image cloaking, integrating them into a mobile app can be a bit tricky, especially when considering commercial use.

To achieve image cloaking in a mobile app for commercial purposes, you might want to explore alternative methods. One approach is to implement client-side image transformations before uploading them. This involves applying image processing techniques directly on the user's device to alter facial features in a reversible manner, making it more challenging for facial detection algorithms to extract meaningful information.

Consider leveraging image processing libraries like OpenCV or TensorFlow Lite for on-device transformations. Implementing a combination of techniques such as blurring, noise addition, or feature distortion can help achieve the desired cloaking effect.

It's crucial to strike a balance between privacy protection and maintaining usability. Additionally, consult legal experts to ensure compliance with privacy regulations when implementing such features in your mobile app.

Remember that the effectiveness of these methods may vary, and staying informed about advancements in AI and privacy protection is essential to adapt your approach accordingly.

If anyone has specific insights or alternative solutions, feel free to share your expertise!

Hope this helps!

Comment: AI generated content is [currently banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035) on Stack Overflow. Please read the [AI Policy](/help/ai-policy) for more information.

Comment: @Liam AI-generated question is banned here not asking about AI-generated content.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue for now by adding watermarks to the contents & some image modifications.